# ReentrantLock demo: signal & return value; => Unlocked?

Tags: java, concurrency, reentrantlock

I am trying to learn basic concepts of Java 8 Concurrent Programming and 
can not understand the *Unlock with return* in a demo snippet here : 
http://www.javatips.net/api/thinking-java-master/src/main/java/ch21concurrent/examples/ConditionBoundedBuffer.java

```
// BLOCKS-UNTIL: notEmpty
public  T take() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        while (count == 0)
            notEmpty.await();
        T x = items[head];
        items[head] = null;
        if (++head == items.length)
            head = 0;
        --count;
        notFull.signal();
        return x;         // <<< RETURN without UNLOCK ? <<<
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

I read about the motivation try / finally for a secure Unlock,
but what about the *'return x'* here, is the monitor proc. then unlocked 
with this return ?

Comment: No. Why would it be unlocked with the return?

Comment: It *is* unlocked. That's what the `finally` block does. Learn more about `finally` here: [The Java™ Tutorials - The finally Block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html). First sentence says it all: *The finally block **always** executes when the try block exits.* That means, even when caused by `return`.

Comment: Interesting and confused me a bit, that means: At first finally and then 'return x'